# Is computer animation becoming cheaper?

Tags: production, animation

[*Kung Fu Panda 4*'s budget is less than 60% of the last one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_Panda). Is this partially due to animation becoming cheaper?

I'm sure there could be other factors, like if they didn’t expect to make as much and put less resources into it. And maybe they are just paying people less, though this could be because the work is easier with more advanced software and a bigger pool of animators to choose from.

I'm asking about the technical aspects to see if that is cheaper. I would imagine the GPUs required have decreased in relative price at least.

Comment: Yes, undoubtedly. Computers are far cheaper and faster than they used to be, and the software used cheaper, faster, and easier to use. Rendering time has reduced dramatically, and things that used to take hours to render a frame can do so in minutes or seconds. Software such as Blender and game engines like Unreal Engine can automate visual effects and other things, such as animating crowds.

Comment: Do movies use automated animation?

Comment: It is much cheaper to reuse the existing computer models and digital sets for sequels. That's why they constantly add mini-movies to animated films; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mPpd-MSjjvw / https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybar3Q0Caf4 etc etc

Comment: Other sequels did not see such a significant budget decrease.

Comment: Not to mention that the significant portion of the voice cast (the Five) are not in KFP4... that cuts the budget a lot

Comment: Still, there's also progress in quality of CGI - while you could do similar thing cheaper, you could also do better for the same money.

Comment: Maybe it's just [Dreamworks doing cost cutting](https://www.cbr.com/kung-fu-panda-4-budget-box-office-projections/), also there were no The Furious Five, so that saved some money too.

Answer (score -8):

Yes, absolutely! The original Tron only used Phong shading and took several minutes of 10 MHz mainframe time per film frame.

My graphics card does 9 TRILLION ops/second and renders near-phographic animation in realtime. New cards can generate realtime people so realistic that chinese crooks used them to fool the victim by conversations with a simulated bank manager who was a real manager deepfaked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just because something can be done quicker doesn't mean that it can be done cheaper.

Comment: You're right. Next time in second life, I'll use 4-color CGA to  save money.